# I got an error when starting mysql: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11

Tags: mysql, nfs

when removed the ibdata1 it worked, and I cant understand how it happened.
I checked with ps and there was no mysql process. also permissions were ok.
Is there a way to check the integrity of this file?

Comment: This really belongs on serverfault.com, but normally this means you still have a (possibly corrupt) mysql process running. Check `ps` & possibly kill those processes. Although usually a graceful stop (`/etc/init.d/mysql stop`) would be prefered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one of the issue using NFS for MySQL , one quick solution can be found on

http://onaxer.com/blog/blog/2010/06/01/innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-37/

Comment: Link is bad - do you have another?

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart mysql with the wrong user at some point?  What were the permissions on the file and the directory it was in?

Answer (score 0):

I guess some other process is talking to this resource/file you don't have the right permissions on that file.
You could restart the computer as an easy solution.
If that does not help, you need to find out out who else is using that file.
But first, check permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this is a known bug when using mysql on NFS.